# Turn array containing array of numbers into formatted version

Tags: javascript

Trying to solve this puzzle in JavaScript:

Input: An array containing x amoung of arrays of numbers.  Heres example:

```
[
[1,4],
[6,8],
[10]
]
```

Expected Output: I would want to run some sort of code to turn it into:

```
1-4,6-8,10
```

I've tried join("-") and tried the same thing within a forEach() loop but can't quite get it to work

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: `forEach` isn’t needed at all. Have you tried [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` the array and `join` each item by a dash, then `join` the resulting array.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 4],
  [6, 8],
  [10]
]

const res = arr.map(e => e.join('-')).join()
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array, [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) up each nested array with a dash, and then finally join up the array that `map` returns into a comma-delimited string.

```js
const arr = [[1,4],[6,8],[10]];

const out = arr.map(a => a.join('-')).join(',');

console.log(out);
```